# Recording from PyAudio is extremely sped up

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I am trying to create a script that automatically records my parrot's audio impressions to [Spotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify) songs. However, I am encountering an issue where the recording is sped up multiple times. Here is my code (the problem is probably in the inner *while* loop of the recording function or saving audio):

```
import os, spotipy, json, datetime
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Audio
import pyaudio, wave

# Database
import mysql.connector

rate = 48000

def save_audio(audio, frames, song):
    # Absolute path to audio_files directory
    audio_file_path = os.path.abspath("audio_files")
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(audio_file_path, song + ".wav")):
        # Check current largest number
        curr_largest_num = 1
        while True:
            if os.path.exists(f"{os.path.join(audio_file_path, song)} ({curr_largest_num}).wav"):
                curr_largest_num += 1
            else:
                break

        # Save file with that number + 1
        with wave.open(f"{os.path.join(audio_file_path, song)} ({curr_largest_num}).wav", "wb") as waveFile:
            waveFile.setnchannels(2)
            waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
            waveFile.setframerate(rate)
            waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    else:
        with wave.open(os.path.join(audio_file_path, song + ".wav"), "wb") as waveFile:
            waveFile.setnchannels(2)
            waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
            waveFile.setframerate(rate)
            waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))


def record():
    try:
        load_dotenv()
        PASSWORD = os.getenv("PASSWORD")

        # Connect to the database
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = "localhost",
            user = "root",
            passwd = PASSWORD,
            database = "parrot_music_taste"
        )
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        # Spotify
        client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
        client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
        redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8888/callback"
        scope = 'user-read-currently-playing'

        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id,
                                                       client_secret=client_secret,
                                                       redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                                                       scope=scope))

        curr_playing = sp.current_user_playing_track()

        # Wait for Spotify to play the song
        if(not curr_playing["is_playing"]):
            print("waiting to play song")
        while not curr_playing["is_playing"]:
            curr_playing = sp.current_user_playing_track()
        print("setup done")

        # This loop records all songs
        while True:
            audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
            stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=2, rate=rate, input=True,
                                 input_device_index = 2, frames_per_buffer=1024)
            frames = []

            song = sp.current_user_playing_track()["item"]["name"]
            # This loop records one song
            while True:
                # Record
                data = stream.read(1024)
                frames.append(data)

                # Check if the song changed
                curr_playing = sp.current_user_playing_track()
                if curr_playing["item"]["name"] != song:
                    print("song changed")

                    stream.stop_stream()
                    stream.close()
                    audio.terminate()

                    audio_file_path = os.path.abspath("audio_files")
                    with wave.open(os.path.join(audio_file_path, song + ".wav"), "wb") as waveFile:
                        waveFile.setnchannels(2)
                        waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
                        waveFile.setframerate(rate)
                        waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
                    break

                song = curr_playing["item"]["name"]

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("KeyboardInterrupt")

record()
```

Please note that this code works fine. So I don't understand what the issue is:

```
import pyaudio, wave, os

audio_file_path = os.path.abspath("audio_files")

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1,
                rate=44100, input=True, input_device_index = 2,
                frames_per_buffer=1024)

print("recording")

frames = []
try:
    while True:
        data = stream.read(1024)
        frames.append(data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("KeyboardInterrupt")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

with wave.open(f"{os.path.join(audio_file_path, 'recording')}.wav", "wb") as waveFile:
    waveFile.setnchannels(1)
    waveFile.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
    waveFile.setframerate(44100)
    waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    frames.clear()
```

How can I solve this issue?